# Jenkins cannot read Github password since upgrading to Git client plugin 2.1.0

Tags: windows-server-2012, git, jenkins, github

I'm currently using Jenkins 1.650 on Windows 2012 and I've upgraded a test instance of Jenkins (cloned from my production server) to 2.25.

As part of this the Git Client plugin was upgraded from 1.19.6 to 2.1.0 and now it cannot authenticate.

I have jobs which run perfectly if I downgrade this plugin again, but when running them using the upgraded plugin the jobs fail. The error output for all is the same:

```
08:18:40 Cloning the remote Git repository
08:18:40 Cloning repository https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git
08:18:40  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project # timeout=10
08:18:40 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git
08:18:40  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
08:18:40 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
08:18:40  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
08:18:41 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
08:18:41 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
08:18:41 stdout: 
08:18:41 stderr: '*dds23' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
08:18:41 operable program or batch file.
08:18:41 error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Windows\TEMP\pass6274847349411211542.bat'
08:18:41 bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
08:18:41 error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
08:18:41 fatal: could not read Password for 'https://user@github.com': No error
08:18:41 
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1745)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
08:18:41    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
08:18:41    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1054)
08:18:41    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
08:18:41    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
08:18:41    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
08:18:41    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
08:18:41    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:401)
08:18:41 ERROR: null
08:18:41 Archiving artifacts
08:18:41 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
08:18:41 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project\server.project\server.distribution\target\htmldocs\documentation to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\project\htmlreports\documentation
08:18:41 ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project\server.project\server.distribution\target\htmldocs\documentation' does not exist.
08:18:41 [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
08:18:41 [BFA] No failure causes found
08:18:41 [BFA] Done. 0s
08:18:41 Started calculate disk usage of build
08:18:41 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
08:18:41 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
08:18:41 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
08:18:42 Sending e-mails to: bob@yeah
08:18:43 Finished: FAILURE
```

Not sure what's changed with this plugin to suddenly cause this failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is summarised here:

[How do I change Jenkins Git plugin from using GIT_ASKPASS to .gitcredentials](https://serverfault.com/questions/823152/how-do-i-change-jenkins-git-plugin-from-using-git-askpass-to-gitcredentials)

However in short there are known bugs with Jenkins 2+ in a Windows environment with reading passwords which contains a character which requires Windows escaping in the command prompt.

I changed the password for the Github account and this resolved the authentication issue.